# How can I used VBA to determine whether the code is in break mode

Tags: ms-access, vba

Why?

I have a got focus even on MyControl as follows

```
If IsNull(Me.MyControl.Value) Then

     Me.MyControl.Value = "FREDDY"
     SendKeys "{F2}"

End If
```

This works fine and places the cursor at the end of the text FREDDY, to allow the user to easily add to the text.

However, if I put a break point on the sendkeys line, and "skip over", the Object explorer is opened in the design environment.  (ie F2 is issued to the design environment!)

I have had this problem elsewhere in different scenarios.

How can I stop the sendkeys line from executing if in debug mode?

Note that

```
screen.ActiveForm.Name
```

always returns the name of the active form, even when the code window "has the focus".

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look up conditional compilation

Comment: @Meehow  I looked this up.  I don't see how this can be applied to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think VBA can detect this.

General recommendations (in this order):

1. Avoid (where possible) commands that create problems while debugging - see other answer.
2. Set your breakpoints (or `Stop` commands) wisely - *after* the problematic line, or before and after, and "Run" (F5) over them instead of stepping through.
3. If you notice while debugging that the next line probably won't work, use Right-click -> `Set Next Statement` to skip the line.

Answer (score 3):

Declare a public boolean at the top of one of the module code sheets.

```
Public GLOBAL_RUNTIME_MODE as Boolean   'initialized as False
'optionally set it right here when you've stopped debugging.
'GLOBAL_RUNTIME_MODE = True
```

Anywhere you want to avoid running code during your debugging sessions, wrap the global boolean into a conditional statement around the code lines.

```
Me.MyControl.Value = "FREDDY"
If GLOBAL_RUNTIME_MODE  Then
    SendKeys "{F2}"
End If
```

Change the public variable in a single place to affect all of the conditions when you've completed debugging.

```
GLOBAL_RUNTIME_MODE = True
```

Comment: That is a nice solution.

Comment: This would work.  It's not very slick though!  It sounds like there may not be a way of automating the detection.   I generally have this sort of problem when using the screen object to get the activeform or control.   Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`SendKeys` should be a last resort if nothing else is possible. Because of side effects like the one you are experiencing.

A better way is to change the `.SelStart` property:

```
With Me.MyControl
    .Value = "FREDDY"
    .SelStart = .SelLength
End With
```

This deselects the text and puts the cursor at the end.